# First derivative test of multiple variables

Tags: derivatives

I have a function:

$$f(x, \lambda) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + \lambda(1-x_1 - x_2 - x_3)$$

If I take the first derivative test, what should I interprete from the results about the critical points $f(x*, \lambda*)$?

Comment: critical points are at 0?

Comment: Hi Markoff, thanks for the answer. my question was incomplete actually. now I have edited it. please check

Comment: do you want to find maximum value of $x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3$ subject to the constraint $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$?

Comment: I am trying to get a critical point by taking the first derivative. I am given the condition $x_1 +x_2+x_3 = 1$, but that can be used after taking the derivative test. My prob is when I take the partial derivative, I get $1-x_1 -x_2-x_3$ for $d f/d \lambda$. How can I solve for the solution using the condition?

Comment: $2x_1=\lambda, 2x_2=\lambda, 2x_3=\lambda$ >> $x_1=x_2=x_3=1/3$

Comment: I got that already. How to find the actual solution from there?!

Comment: So critical point is at $x_1=x_2=x_3=1/3$. Does it answer your question or I am missing something?